# HP DL360 G6 NC328i Dual Port Gigabit - Windows Server 2003 R2 Driver Problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp

I recently installed Windows Server 2003 R2 (64) on a DL360 G6 without using the SmartStart CD (it didn't like the MSDN media).  But when I attempted to install the network drivers post-install using the packages from the HP website, I wasn't successful.  Though I selected the correct package, the installer reported I did not have the necessary hardware configuration.  Has anyone had a similar experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Smart Update manger that is part of the Smart Start CD?  I have found running hpsum.exe that is in the latest Support Pack will often address problem drivers.  Seems there is some part that a manual install misses.  Has solved problem NIC drivers a number of times for me
[DL360 Support Pack 64Bit](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=ca&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884319&prodNameId=3884320&swEnvOID=1113&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-ed3c3a5c369642afa9f8215279)

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  Still not sure what was wrong with the individual packages I downloaded from hp.com.

Comment: It remaians one of lifes little mysteries.  :-)  I know there is a management piece or monitor that the card wants first but the Support Pack usually finds whatever is needed.